# Git clone bitbucket repository inside aws ec2 using ssm , can't see ssh public keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, ssm

when I try to clone my private repository from bitbucket to my ec2 instance using ssm agent I get

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

after invistagation I found that ssm command for some resone cant see any of my public keys in ~/.ssh/ , how to git clone from bitbucket using ssm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that SSM or any command like startup commands when machine run as root and what I found that root doesn't have permissions to read or any access to ssh public and private keys.

So my solution "I think it is work around but work for me"

- Change current user to root  `sudo su`
- Go to shh directory `cd .ssh`
- copy key files or regenerate ssh keys here